Is it possible to convert a parser made with YACC to a Haskell parser combinator?
I am looking at updating an old project that contained a YACC parser generator for parsing a specific file type. I want to improve the performance of this tool and was considering updating the parser. In searching for a better solution I cam across this library: FlatParse by Andras Kovacs. Is it possible to rewrite the YACC parser and lexer to use this or another Haskell-based parser, and is there a possibility this would improve the performance of the parsing?
I've started looking into Haskell parsing but am not sure what the difference is between parser generators and parser combinators is and whether you can reasonably convert one to the other.

I would be surprised if you could salvage much of anything when converting a yacc-style parser into a parser-combinator parser. You might have some success with happy, but I haven't tried it.

Are you new to Haskell as well, or just new to parser combinators?

What makes you think changing from yacc will improve the performance? That would be very surprising.

@K.A.Buhr new to Haskell and parser combinators, so apologies if the question seems a bit uninformed

@user207421 I would have thought there is a more modern parsing/lexing solution since yacc is a pretty old tool. Is it still a good option in terms of performance compared to other parser generators like Bison, ANTLR, Boost Spirit, etc?

That’s not what I asked. Of course there are more modern tools. But ‘more modern’ does not necessarily equate to improved performance, and I doubt that replacing yacc will have any effect. I was parsing 50,000 lines/min with yacc 35 years ago. I don't know much about the other technologies you mention except that Bison is just a rewrite of yacc, and that yacc parses in linear time. I would be looking at your I/O strategies and maybe the lexer.

If it is possible to get a more efficient parser by using parser combinators, it's most likely that would be achievable by making use of the more flexible features that the parser combinator system has that YACC doesn't have. And that would likely mean completely redesigning the structure of your parser. If you directly "convert" your parser, the result will most likely use combinators to just do what the YACC parser did. A simple conversion might make sense if your goal is to get it into Haskell land so you can talk to it from Haskell, but I would be doubtful it would end up any faster.

Yacc parsers tend to be pretty fast.  By restricting the generality of the parser, Yacc can build a pretty efficient table-based implementation without backtracking.
The main benefit of combinator-based parsers is that they are a lot more flexible and easier to work with.  If I was writing a parser from scratch for a language that didn't already have a Yacc-friendly formal grammar, I'd use a combinator library because it would probably be faster to develop (and a lot more fun).  I wouldn't typically expect to produce a parser that could outperform a Yacc parser, though.
The main conceptual difference between Yacc and combinator parsers is that Yacc defines a relatively simple declarative language for specifying parsing rules that supports sequencing and alternation and can invoke statements of the host language only at a reduction step:
records : records CRLF record  { append_records($1, $2); }   | record {...}
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^
                |                    |                       |
           sequencing       limited use of host          alternation
                          language at reduction

as well as a few other fixed features, like associativity declarations with implied precedence, some error handling and recovery extensions, etc.
In contrast, a combinator parsing library is designed to use the host language itself as the means for specifying the parsing rules, with the implication that the full power and flexibility of the host language is available throughout the whole parsing operation.
So, you can typically still express sequencing and alternation:
records = singleton <$> record  <|>  cons <$> record <*> records
                                ^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            alternation            sequencing

but these are expressions in the host language using host language operators, function calls, declarations, etc.   Most importantly, you can define new combinators as functions in the host language:
some thing = singleton <$> thing  <|>  cons <$> thing <*> some thing

which you can then re-use in your rules:
records = some record

By itself, this combinator some maybe isn't too impressive, but you can write combinators like between that parse something (e.g., an expression) between two other things (e.g., open and closed parentheses) or sepBy that parse zero or more of one thing (e.g., an identifier) separated by another thing (e.g., a comma).  With a modest standard library of decent combinators, and some application-specific combinators of your own, you can write very succinct and easily maintained parsers.
The cost is that, as mentioned above, Yacc's intentionally restrictive declarative language can easily be compiled into a high-performance table-driven state machine.  In contrast, combinator-based parsers are compiled just like any other host language code, and unless the host language compiler is unusually good at identifying opportunities to transform code into high-performance state machines, you aren't likely to get a faster parser from a combinator library.  In the best case, you get comparable performance.
So, if you already have a working Yacc parser and are primarily interested in improving its performance, I don't think converting it to a Haskell combinator library is going to help much.  I don't have any first-hand experience with FlatParse, and it sounds like it's an unusually performant combinator-based parser, but I still wouldn't expect that to translate to a big performance improvement.
Some other practical considerations...
You should definitely do some benchmarking and/or profiling to determine what, precisely, is contributing to poor performance.  I guess I'd be surprised if the parser was the culprit and, if it is, it seems more likely that the performance problem will be the host language code that produces the final parse result, rather than the Yacc-generated parsing code.
You could consider trying some Yacc-compatible or Yacc-like alternatives.  It should be easy to convert a Yacc parser to a Bison parser, and while I wouldn't expect a significant performance improvement, you might get lucky.  I found an old technical report from U Arizona where the authors claim to have prototyped a plug-in Yacc replacement that compiles to a "hard-coded" instead of table driven parser, and they claim performance gains of 2-6 times.  Unfortunately, that seemed like an early prototype that wasn't available for download, and I couldn't find any recent work by the authors.  It might be worth contacting them or looking through some of their references, though.
Also be warned that Haskell may also not be the best target language for your specific problem.  If you are trying to integrate a new parser into an existing C project, writing Haskell code to be called from C code isn't as straightforward as, say, integrating C and Rust.  Haskell also has a pretty steep learning curve, both in general and when it comes to the specifics of writing high-performance code.  That's before you even get into the learning curve for combinator-based parsing.
